# How to make css class code reusable like Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I’m trying to understand how bootstrap works, right now I’m not interested in how responsive functionality works, I’m only interested in how adding class to element will change its appearance.

For example adding class="checkbox-inline" to label like this

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
```

will give you this shape

[image]

I’m trying to do the same thing using css and jQuery, but the problem is I need multiple divs to do this

```
<div class="buttoun-toggle">
    <div id="line"></div>
    <div id="circle"></div>
</div>
```

and with some css it will give me this shape

[image]

also I did the animation using jQuery (when you click it, it will move).

So what I did is so simple, create circle and square with rounded edge to make my button...

No the problem is this code is not reusable because I can't just use

```
<label class="buttoun-toggle">
```

to create this button again, and that mainly because it has three divs in it.
So what I need to know how Bootstrap has this code reusability and how I could do the same thing here, meaning how could I call class and all those div get called?

Comment: Bootstrap uses several techniques developed over time. One of them that might interest you (but does not answers question completely) is **pseudo elements**

Comment: Well, the bootstrap provides you with an excellent example, is there something you don't understand when you look at the code of Bootstrap CSS?

Comment: How does bootstrap do it?  Right click, inspect, look at the css panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would usually use pseudo-elements like, `before` and `after` to accomplish a composition of elements that are tied to one class:

```css
.toggle-button {
  position: relative;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #CECECE;
  float: left;
}

.toggle-button::after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: -20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-top: -3px;
}

.toggle-button-red::after {
  background-color: red;
}

.toggle-button-blue::after {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle-button toggle-button-red"></div>
<div class="toggle-button toggle-button-blue"></div>
```